# How to filter the date column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I want to remove the date in the `column['DATE']` and use the `quickfilter`.

I do this:

```
quickfilter = (df_dexu.DATE < 2018-12-1)
df_dexu=df_dexu[quickfilter]
```

but it gives the error message:

> TypeError: invalid type comparison

Comment: `2018-12-1` is not a date. That is 2018 minus 12 minus 1, i.e. number 2005. That cannot be compared to a date.

Answer (score 2):

Try convert column [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
quickfilter = (pd.to_datetime(df_dexu.DATE) < '2018-12-01')
```

Or:

```
df_dexu.DATE = pd.to_datetime(df_dexu.DATE)
quickfilter = (df_dexu.DATE < '2018-12-01')
```